# Something strange with the john tag wiki

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

The [page](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags/john/info) about [john](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john) reads:

> The Fourth Gospel, which is generally held to be written by John the son of Zebedee.

This is the description I submitted.

But on [the page](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags) where you can see all the tags, it's cropped to:

> generally held to be written by John the son of Zebedee.

I think my description is a bit better, but this is fine too.  What isn't fine, is having two, separate descriptions depending on where you are looking.  Is this a SE bug or data problem?

Comment: I feel like I've seen this before. My guess is that the SE software looks for the word "is" and cuts off everything before it assuming that you began the tag wiki "John is..."

Comment: How about trying "The Fourth Gospel, generally held to be written by John the son of Zebedee."

Comment: You shouldn't say "generally held".  It's called the Gospel of John for a reason, we shouldn't let the modern textual critics dictate their ambiguity to us.

Comment: @Lance I agree - in this case (unlike some others) the author makes clear his identity and I see no reason to explicitly cast doubt on that in the tag wiki.

Comment: @Jack and Lance: According to Wikipedia: "The Gospel's authorship is anonymous," and "According to most modern scholars, John was not the author of any of these books."  Since there are legitimate questions about the authorship, it really seems like a good idea to not be too assertive about it.

Comment: Wikipedia also [has an article dedicated to this question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disciple_whom_Jesus_loved). I'm unconvinced there are any other reasonable candidates given what we do know from the author (eg he was there for the Last Supper, etc). What do you think @Lance?

Comment: I think the references to "the disciple whom Jesus loved" in 13:23-25, 19:25-35, 21:2-7, and 21:20-24 give good evidence.  A good quote I found that relates to my answer on Hebrews is: _"In fact, when one leaves out of consideration the heretics mentioned by Irenaeus (Adv. Haer. 3.11.9) and Epiphanius (Haer. 51.3), no one in the church seriously questioned the authenticity of the Gospel of John until the rise of biblical criticism in the eighteenth century."_  Theophilus of Antioch (c.181) and Irenaeus (130-c.200) both identify John as the author.  That's what I can fit in a comment.

Comment: @Lance: I asked [the question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1039/68) so that you would have more than a comment-space to answer it in.  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soldarnal's comment was correct:

> My guess is that the SE software looks for the word "is" and cuts off everything before it assuming that you began the tag wiki "John is..."

The excerpt (pending approval) will read:

> The Fourth Gospel attributed to John the son of Zebedee.

That's better phrasing anyway.

I went ahead and asked about [who wrote the gospel](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1039/68) and filled in the tag wiki to cover the potential confusion with other John-related tags.